# FIREBASE can I set password to account created with facebook or google?

Tags: facebook, firebase, authentication, passwords

Is it possible set/create password when user was created with Facebook or Google account?

I tried using link account but I cannot recreate the account with the email and then link it

Answer (score 1):

No:  Facebook, Twiter or even GitHub will not let you perform this action for security purpose. Please refer to this link:[enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)

Answer (score 0):

No. Facebook and Google users will have to use the passwords for those specific accounts. They cannot be changed through Firebase, only through Facebook, Google, or whatever platform they are coming from. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin